# Interpreting Independent Components using FastICA in R

Tags: r

I've recently conducted an Independent Component Analysis using `fastICA` in R. I have obtained a matrix of independent components.  How do I figure out what variables these components are made of? For example, component #4 (v4) has a value for each of the n = 400 observations.  What is this? Which variables were used to create this v4?

This is the code that was used: `ica_new<-fastICA (final,n.comp = 40, alg.typ = "parallel", fun = "logcosh", alpha = 1,
method = "C", row.norm = FALSE, maxit = 200, tol = 0.0001, verbose = TRUE)`

I found this code for PCA: `## varimax with normalize = TRUE is the default
fa <- factanal( ~., 2, data = swiss)
varimax(loadings(fa), normalize = FALSE)
promax(loadings(fa))`

EDIT: So thanks to @Hack-R I think the code I will need to use would look something like this `ica_new<-fastICA (final,n.comp = 40, alg.typ = "parallel", fun = "logcosh", alpha = 1,
method = "C", row.norm = FALSE, maxit = 200, tol = 0.0001, verbose = TRUE, firstEig = 1, lastEig = nrow(final))`
`
Is this accurate? EDIT: Doesn't Run

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On this site in general -- and much more so in the R tag -- we strongly encourage including a reproducible example with your question. So please include the code an data to produce the ICA. Maybe you want to use one of the examples from the documentation like `S <- cbind(sin((1:1000)/20), rep((((1:200)-100)/100), 5));A <- matrix(c(0.291, 0.6557, -0.5439, 0.5572), 2, 2);
X <- S %*% A;
a <- fastICA(X, 2, alg.typ = "parallel", fun = "logcosh", alpha = 1, 
             method = "R", row.norm = FALSE, maxit = 200, 
             tol = 0.0001, verbose = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I apologize and have added the code used.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the example. For it to be reproducible I think we still need the object `final`). I will update my answer shortly.